# How can some one earn a large number of points by posting 1 question but got 5 upvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, accepted-answer

I just wonder how someone in StackOverflow can earn a large number of points in a week but just with 1 question and 5 upvotes.

I found [Ugur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10185782/ugur) as one of those who earned the highest number of the reputation for the week (315 during the last 4 days).

I tried to analyze his activities to see what sort of activities he was involved to earn such a large reputation in a short time. But I was astonished to see that he has asked only 1 question during his lifetime and the question has 5 upvotes.

Also, he has answered his own question to earn points worth 300? How comes someone can earn such huge points for his own answer? Who will accept the answer? Can someone enlighten me?

I also have questions open for a while on StackFlow without an answer. I have found an answer myself. Will I earn such huge points if I answer my own question?

Thanks
Rinsad

Comment: There was a 300 rep bounty on that question he answered. You will not earn that much for answering your own question unless someone also puts a bounty on your question.

Comment: Could you explain who is going to give a bounty?

Comment: [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) from the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Basically OP posted a question. Presumably someone else came along and found the question interesting (this is just speculation) and placed a bounty on the question. OP ended up answering their own question and the person who placed the bounty awarded it to OP.

Comment: If the person thinks the answer is worth and accept only the bounty will be awarded to the one who answered right? BTW, is there a special filter on SO to find questions worth a bounty?

Comment: There are a few scenarios for how a bounty is awarded. You can find them in the previous link I provided. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) is a link to all SO questions that currently have a bounty placed on them (you can find it by going to the Featured tab on SO).

Comment: That's worth learning. If you had put an answer I would have accepted it for you. Still, you can if my question is worth an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also, he has answered his own question to earn points worth 300? How
>   comes someone can earn such huge points for his own answer?

Underneath the vote count you can see a +300, which means the user was awarded a 300 rep bounty for their answer.

[image: screenshot of 300 points awarded for bounty]

> I also have questions open for a while on StackFlow without an answer.
>   I have found an answer myself. Will I earn such huge points if I
>   answer my own question?

No, you will not earned that many point *just* for answering your own question. Someone would need to place a bounty on the question and your answer would have to be awarded the bounty (or a lot of people would have to simply upvote your answer).

> I tried to analyze his activities to see what sort of activities he
>   was involved to earn such a large reputation in a short time.

You can see a complete breakdown of any user's reputation change by going to their profile, selecting the **Activity** tab and then select the **Reputation** tab. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10185782/ugur?tab=reputation) is a link to the user in question's reputation tab. You can see the breakdown of how they earned 315 points in 4 days.

[image]

For further reading, see [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).